# Хостинг для телеграм бота Heroku

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, heroku, hosting

Хотел попросить помощи/советов как правильно задеплоить бота на хостинг. Я за все время занимался этим только один раз и то это было очень давно и тот бот не имел столько функции как в этот раз. То что я меня интересует это хостинг HEROKU(ну или же у вас есть какие-либо другие хорошие предложения буду рад прочесть). У меня есть бот структура которого разделена на несколько файлов, для того чтобы более понятно есть основной файл main.py в котором происходит все соединения и начало работы бота, и есть второстепенные файлы к примеру profile.py, help.py в которых просто находятся команды для бота. Так вот, в боте так же находятся база данных SQLITE3 и API соединения.

Я посмотрел несколько гайдов, а так же просто из того что сам знаю это закинул весь бот на GITHUB, после присоединил репозиторий к HEROKU, и задеплоил так как оно есть без каких либо проверок или что-то в этом роде так как я больше ничего не понимаю в этом.

Проблемы с которыми я столкнулся такие:
База данных, как сделать чтобы HEROKU или же в GITHUB происходили изменения в базе данных когда это надо.

Объясняю ситуацию:
Есть команда которая создает профиль и вносит информацию в базу данных. А есть проверка типо если она есть больше не создавать и так далее(думаю вы и сами понимаете о чем речь), и если пользователь уже есть в базе данных то это проверяется по IP и один пользователь не может сделать себе несколько раз профиль, только изменять через специальные для этого команды. Но это не происходит после деплоя, бот каждый раз выполняет команды с самого начал несмотря создавал пользователь до этого профиль или же нет.

Вторая проблема это соединение API:
В коде есть очень много команд которые используют API из интернета. И после деплоя они никак не взаимодействуют с командами.

В основном вот с этим я столкнулся при хостинге бота на HEROKU.
Был бы рад если поможете понять всю суть работы с хостингами как и что делать, спасибо.

p.s. (все остальные простые команды которые не относятся к базе данных или же API работают нормально [написал для того если кому-то понадобится это информация])

Comment: Используйте платный тариф или VPS сервер, у heroku много ограничений

Comment: @ClarkDevlin а через какую програму лучше всего работать с vps сервером. Например filezilla норм или есть что то по лучше?

Comment: что значит через какую программу? По ssh - putty, по sftp - winscp, есть всё в одном, напримера, mobaxterm. Смотря что требуется

Comment: Спасибо, все сделал. Просто интересовался из-за того что это мой первый опыт с работой всего этого.